# Store contents of text for as array with VB

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I'm trying to do something quite simple. I need to take a pipe-delimited text file and store the contents of the file in an array.

Comment: You should up-vote Rob P. as well, since he gave you the right answer (and he posted it first). Typically, if both answers are equal, you should accept the one that was posted first. that's up to you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done vb.net for at least a year but I'll give it a go:

First of all read in all of the file you have

```
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myFile.txt")
```

Then split the file by the pipe character:

```
var fileSplit = fileContent.Split("|")
```

`fileSplit` will be your string array of the file separated by the pipe character.

I haven't tested this and the syntax is by memory but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out :-)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this - File.ReadAllText (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

Then you can use .Split() on your delimiter (the pipe) to get an array of strings.